# how to avoid duplicate values in db context object in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[rendertutorials](@courname nvarchar(30))
AS
BEGIN

SELECT 
  tu.FkCategoryid AS Fcatid 
  ,tu.Title
  ,tu.content
  ,tu.Keywords
  ,tu.Metadata
  ,tu.tags
  ,cat.CategoryName
  ,cat.CourseName
  ,cat.courseimagepath AS imgpath
FROM GetCategories AS cat 
INNER JOIN GetTutorials AS tu ON cat.CategoryId = tu.FkCategoryId
WHERE tu.publish = 1 AND cat.coursename LIKE '%' + @courname + '%'

END
GO


EXEC[rendertutorials] "mvc"
```

[image]

AS you can see the store procedure will produce the correct data. item[0] ... item[n] are different.

```
 public IActionResult Tutorials()  
 {
    //var data = GetTableLastChanges("listoftitiles @title", 1, "@title");
    var data = db.getrenderview.FromSqlRaw("rendertutorials @courname={0}", "mvc").ToList();
       
    return View(data);
 }
```

But when I call the stored procedure from code the above `data` variable contain the same data (from item[0] till item[n]). Why? What did I miss?

Comment: are you saying , proc return 1 rows while dbcontext same records n time?

Answer (score 0):

use distinct in sql:
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name;